# DRF ForeignKey value not showing partially

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I am newbie in python django, just couple weeks. And this is my first question post.

I found problems using DRF ForeignKey. The foreign key value (name) do not showing up.
I have 3 tables which are related each other (Brand, Country, BrandCountry). After followed some tutorials, in BrandCountry Entity, I succeed print out the name of brand (instead of ID), but it is not working with the same code structure for country relation.
[country name not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD0tM.png)

I wonder what is the problem causing this. There is no error or warning message. I tried to debug, the query run correctly (it selects brand.name and country.name correctly).
[correct query from debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTmvK.png)

I wonder is it because of :
 - I use 'code' for relation key instead of 'ID'?

- the name of the Country contains Kanji(special character)?
- or is there something i miss?

Models.py

```
class BrandCountry(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'brand_countries'

    brand = models.ForeignKey(to='brand.Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ref_brand_country_brand')
    country_code = models.ForeignKey(to='country.Country',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='ref_brand_country_country',
                                    max_length=45,
                                    db_column='country_code',
                                    to_field='code')
```

Serializers.py

```
class BrandCountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='brand.name')
    country_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='country.name')

    class Meta:
        model = BrandCountry
        fields = ('id', 'brand_id', 'brand_name', 'country_code', 'country_name')

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('brand','country_code')
        return queryset
```

Views.py

```
class BrandCountryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BrandCountrySerializer
    brand_id = "brand_id"

    def get_queryset(self):
        serializer_class = BrandCountrySerializer.setup_eager_loading(BrandCountry.objects)
        queryset = serializer_class.all()
        brand_id = self.kwargs.get(self.brand_id)
        queryset = queryset.filter(brand_id=brand_id)

        return queryset
```

I tried to debug and find the solution here and there almost spend more than 1 days, but no result. If there someone can help me, I really appreciate it. Sorry if something is missing or unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **wrong refference** for `country_name` in serializer. So change `source='country.name'` to `source='country_code.name'`

```
class BrandCountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='brand.name')
    country_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='country_code.name') # Change is here <<<<

    class Meta:
        model = BrandCountry
        fields = ('id', 'brand_id', 'brand_name', 'country_code', 'country_name')

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('brand','country_code')
        return queryset
```

**UPDATE**
You can try [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) attribute, as:

```
class BrandCountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BrandCountry
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('brand', 'country_code')
        return queryset
```

Comment: omg, it is so small mistake, i did not realize. Thank you for your answer, really helpful. I tried it and it works perfectly

Comment: Thank for the suggestion also. I will change the model field name also, since it is weird using 'country_code.name'. Yes of course i will "mark as true" for you. sorry cannot upvote, low reputation. Thanks again

Comment: I've updated the answer, You can try that also, *if you wish to work with Nested Serializer*

Comment: Thank you for the new suggestion. I have read documentation and tried to use the depth. it will provide all the fields in the FK, which is effective to use for big relation model. But in my case i only need the "name" field of the FK, so I wont use it now, but maybe I will use it if I found the right case. Thank you again for the suggestion really appreciate it and helpful